# textFieldDidEndEditing moves the screen when not wanted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

In my app, my UITextFields are placed below where the top of the keyboard would be, so I have to move my view up so that the text field is visible over the keyboard when I'm editing. In order to do this I use the UITextFieldDelegate method, textFieldDidBeginEditing:. Then in the method textFieldDidEndEditing:, I move the view back down.

The problem occurs when I try to switch between text fields. When I do, the delegate calls the method textFieldDidEndEditing: then immediately calls textFieldDidBeginEditing: for the other text field, which makes the view go down then immediately up, so it looks like the screen jolts. Is there any workaround for this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just been having the exact same issue, and this is the solution that I came to.

Set up a separate method for handling when your textField's keyboard is resigned, and place your self.view.center realignment in there. This way, you can ensure that your textFieldDidEndEditing method is kept separate.

Here's an example if I haven't explained myself properly. Note that when the user taps on a textField, I place a DONE button in the navigation bar (due to it being a numerical keypad), although you can link this method to the DONE button on a normal keyboard:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UIBarButtonItem *hideKeyboardButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(resignResponder:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:hideKeyboardButton animated:YES];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

//Nothing needs to go here anymore

}

- (void)resignResponder:(id)sender {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    //Use core animation instead of the simple action below in order to reduce 'snapback'
    self.view.center = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, I did not think of that before - but, which method should I move the view up when the text view becomes first responder? Thanks

Comment: Within the textFieldDidBeginEditing method. If you want to make it a bit more smooth, you can do so like this: `CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, -(textField.frame.origin.y - 40), 320, 480);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{self.view.frame = newFrame;}];`

Comment: There's 1 problem, when I put it there the textFieldDidBeginEditing method is called, but not the textFieldDidEndEditing. So, the view moves up over and over again whenever I begin editing another text field.

Comment: If you look at the code I suggested in my previous comment, I made sure the Y-coordinate of the new CGRect is subjective upon the textField being used - therefore the UIView should readjust dynamically. i.e. `CGRectMake(0, -(textField.frame.origin.y - 40), 320, 480);` - where 'textField' is the general method variable (applies to currently-used UITextField)

Comment: No worries. Thanks for accepting this as the answer. If you could up vote my answer too that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Just check in which text field you are (for example, give them `tag`s). Then according to this information, move or don't move your view.

Comment: Where should I implement it? Thank you

Comment: Exactly in these delegate methods, as you did. They pass the text field to the method, so you can check.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to move the textfield is to register for the notifications

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Do the modification of textfield frame in keyboardWillShow: & keyboardWillHide:

Answer (score 0):

I used a different approach to solve this problem:
When switching from one edit control to another (field1 -> field2) you receive the following messages:

- textFieldShouldBeginEditing (field2)
- textFieldShouldEndEditing (field1)
- textFieldDidEndEditing (field1)
- textFieldDidBeginEditing (field2)

What I do is to use a counter variable (x):

- Add  x+=1 in textFieldShouldBeginEditing
- Add  x-=1 in textFieldShouldEndEditing

Then:

- in textFieldDidEndEditing stretch the controls to original position if x<0
- in textFieldDidBeginEditing roll up the controls if x>0